# Proof of sum of binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I have two stochastic variable $X\sim B(n,p)$ and $Y\sim B(m,p)$, I need to prove that $Z=X+Y \sim B(n+m,p)$.

> Why is $$\sum_{k=0}^{u} \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{u-k} = \binom{n+m}{u}$$

Comment: Vandermonde's Identity. Look it up.

Comment: This is exactly the Vandermonde convolution/identity. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Answer (score 1):

If you are selecting $(n+m)$ items, $u$ at a time, then, for each selection, you will end up with $k$ of the items, coming from the first $n$, where $k$ must be in $\{0,1,\cdots, u\}$.  Of course, I am assuming that $u \leq n$ and $u \leq m$.

Comment: It is unnecessary to assume $u\leq n$ or $u\leq m$, when conveniently $k>h$ or $k<0$ implies $\tbinom hk=0$